# What will be the return amount of Lic New Endowment Plan 814?

Tags: insurance, life-insurance

I purchased the plan this year (2016). I am paying the premium of 89000 P.A (Approximately inclusive of tax), the policy period of 12 years and my age is 25 years old. What will be the return amount after completion of 12 years (maturity period)?

Comment: @NathanL In Chennai,India.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 2):

The maturity amount can't be predicted in endowment plan. Every year LIC will announce bonus. In the past few years it is in the range of 4-6%.

Assuming 4%, every year, for 12 years, 48% of sum assured. So if the sum assured is 1,00,000/- you will get 1,48,000/- after 12 years.